# Как модифицировать url по которому открывается диалоговое окно?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, java-ee, jsf, primefaces

Правильно ли я понимаю, что всё, что нам нужно от сервера, клиент запрашивает по url. Т.е. запросив url страницы, сервер отдаёт ему html и он отображается пользователю. Так же работают диалоговые окна? Клиент отправляет запрос по url, сервер отдаёт, но всё это отображается в диалоге?

Если всё так, то можно ли как то модифицировать url к диалоговому окну и запихнуть туда, например, mode, чтобы сервер отдал конкретную страницу по конкретному моду?

Comment: приведите пример диалогового окна.

Comment: Обычно, диалоговые окна загружаются вместе со страницей и скрываются с помощью CSS. Когда требуется отобразить диалог, просто меняется стиль, так, чтобы HTML элемент (обычно - DIV) стал видимым. В JSF этот процесс может совмещаться с AJAX-запросом к серверу для обновления состояния содержимого диалога.

Comment: @bobzer а если пошел запрос с обновлением содержимого диалога, он происходит по url родительской страницы?

Comment: Да, по URL текущей страницы. Но обычно он выполняется как AJAX-запрос, поэтому перезагрузка страницы не происходит. Вместо этого содержимое диалога обновляется с помощью JavaScript, а затем он делается видимым